# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
public class Cylinder extends JFrame implements ActionListener{  

    JLabel lblRadius = new JLabel("Enter the Radius");  
    JLabel lblHeight = new JLabel("Enter the Height");  
    JTextField txtRadius  = new JTextField(10);  
    JTextField txtHeight = new JTextField(10);  
    JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");  
    JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");  
    JTextField txtOutput = new JTextField(20);  
    JPanel p = new JPanel();  
    FlowLayout layout;  
    public Cylinder(){  
        super("Calculator");  
        setSize(300,300);  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        layout = new FlowLayout();  
        p.setLayout(layout);  
        p.add(lblRadius);  
        p.add(txtRadius);  
        p.add(lblHeight);  
        p.add(txtHeight);  
        p.add(btnCalculate);  
        p.add(btnClear);  
        p.add(txtOutput);  
        p.add(p);  

        setVisible(true);  

        btnCalculate.addActionListener(this);  
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        Object source = e.getSource();  
        int radius = Integer.parseInt(txtRadius.getText());  
        int height = Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText());  
        if (source.equals(btnCalculate)){  
            double volume = (Math.PI * radius * radius)*height;  
            txtOutput.setText("The Volume is: "+ Math.round(volume));  
        }  

        if (source.equals(btnClear)){  
            txtRadius.setText("");  
            txtHeight.setText("");  
            txtOutput.setText("");  
        }  
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
         new Cylinder();  
    }  
}
```

I am trying to add a GUI to my netbeans project but I get an error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding
>   container's parent to itself  at
>   java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Container.java:472)     at
>   java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1083)   at
>   java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)    at
>   cylinder.Cylinder.(Cylinder.java:38)    at
>   cylinder.Cylinder.main(Cylinder.java:68) Java Result: 1

Comment: `p.add(p);`. That's why.

Comment: Message is really explicit

Comment: Instead of adding `p` to `p`, you need to add `p` to `this` (JFrame)

Comment: Code write-up is important. but try Netbean's JFrame Form

Answer (score 3):

Its because of this line of code

```
p.add(p);
```

**Solution**: change this line to `add(p);` as you can not put panel into itself. I am sure your aim is to put panel on `JFrame` you inherited.